# C# Application Detected By Kaspersky As Trojan Virus (VHO:Trojan.MSIL.Convagent.gen)

Tags: c#, virus, trojan, kaspersky

I developped a C# winform application to import rows from firebird db

when compile i have a message from vstudio that can't access to .exe file then an alert message from kaspersky to notice me from an trojan

pls help.

Comment: I'd suggest to check dlls in individual nuget packages if the issue always arises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved By Changing The Value Of "Generate debug info" to "embedded"

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

"VHO:Trojan-Ransom.MSIL.Convagent.gen" how is fix

[image: VS 2015]

OK, this setting fix. Visual Studio 2015 C# project.

Answer (score 1):

It just happens sometimes. We faced these issues several times with different applications and different antiviruses. Some byte sequence in your program occasionally coincide with known virus ones, so antivirus gives a false-positive actuation. Change something in your program and recompile it - an issue will gone very likely.

Answer (score 1):

Kaspersky it's using the heuristic scan, a technology which checks the code behind for the patterns. Some pieces of the code they are used in the malware programs and it gonna say that they are viruses. I remember that once I've created a service to insert some MySql data for wordpress, he said it's a virus, another time used a geojson to draw a map and it was saying that it's a virus when I've added a piece of code to draw for each city a dot.

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio 2022 Guide**

This might not work for everyone but it helped me.

1. Right Click your Project

[image: Guide Image 1]

2. Scroll down to 'Assembly name' and just randomise it.

[image: Guide Image 2]

This helped me, I kept having this same issue. Kept telling me my software was a trojan because I'm working with Proxies lol.

Answer (score 0):

I created a .Net Core App in Visual Studio then stripped out Bootstrap, JQuery, some validation scripts and brought it down to basics (3MB btw).

I tried Osman Hal's suggestion of creating an application without a manifest (under project properties) and that worked for a little while but I suspect the problem is there's not enough of a signature of (in my case) a Web Application to recognize as a valid executable.

That said the only true solution is is to exclude the Visual Studio directories from File Scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Full steps to solve problem in visual studio 2022:

1- Go to `Properties` of project like this:

[image: Properties of project]

2- On `Build` section click on `Advanced...` like this:

[image: click on Advance]

3- Change `Debugging information` value to `Embedded` like this:

[image: change value]

4- click `OK` and re-run your project.

> Note: if this way not worked add `exe` file to white list of your
> antivirus.

Comment: Very strangely, i have started seeing this error just now. I am using VS 2022 Ent 17.3.6. The option you mentioned (Debugging Information) in now showing up here