# C# Winform Application detected by Kaspersky as Trojan (HEUR:Trojan-Spy.MSIL.Bobik.gen)

Tags: c#, winforms, user32, kaspersky

I have a C# Winform application, Its purpose is copy text in clipboard. But when I build the project I get Kaspersky report as (HEUR:Trojan-Spy.MSIL.Bobik.gen) and it deletes my .exe file. I found that problem from within my source code.

`[DllImport("User32.dll")]`
`public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();`
`[DllImport("User32.dll")]`
`public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);`
`[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]`
`[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]`
`static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);`
`[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]`
`[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]`
`static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);`

```
//Call it in contructor

Public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AddClipboardFormatListener(this.Handle);
    this.FormClosing += (s, e) =>
    {
        RemoveClipboardFormatListener(this.Handle);
    };
    button1.Click += (s, e) =>{
        // Button exit application
        RemoveClipboardFormatListener(this.Handle);
        Application.Exit();
    };
}
```

Please let me know, what went wrong with the above code and how to solve it.
I'm trying a some way from [C# Application Detected By Kaspersky As Trojan Virus (VHO:Trojan.MSIL.Convagent.gen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916286), but not working for me.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The antivirus suspects that your program is doing something nefarious. You may wish to re-evaluate your program design.

Comment: yes, the use DllImportAttribute  listener and get values from clipboard made the antivirus detect it to the Trojan. I'm looking for another way.